# How come onEditorActionListener() has a TextView as its parameter rather than an EditText?

Tags: java, android

I am a confuse about the following code:

```
EditText test = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
test.setOnEditorActionListener(new onEditorActionListener(){
@Override
   public boolean onEditor Action(TextView v, int actionID, keyEvent event){
       return true
    }
});
```

So my question is why does a TextView gets pass in as a parameter rather than the EditText? Does this also means that EditText and TextView are the same exact thing?

Comment: I am sorry for the misspelled above it should be onEditorAction not onEditor Action. I am new to this site so I am not so sure how to reedit my post.

Comment: An EditText is a subclass of TextView. If you look at its source, it is described as a "thin veneer" over the TextView class, as TextView has pretty much all of EditText's functionality, but it just can't be directly edited by the user through the GUI. A TextView is used as the parameter type so that any TextView subclass may be used with that interface.

Comment: Oh now that makes sense but there is one last thing that kinda bother me which is why not give an EditText as the parameter but a TextView instead?

Comment: Using a broader type like TextView allows more flexibility in the types that the interface can work with. For example, if you want to create a View similar to an EditText, but without, say, the blinking cursor, or the drawn baseline, you can instead extend TextView without having to override those properties of EditText.

Comment: Ah I see this makes so much more sense thanks and sorry to bother you but my last question is how can I put this question as solved so others don't get confuse?

Comment: I could put my comments in an answer you can mark as accepted, if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

```
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
           ↳    android.widget.EditText
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) -- you can see that `EditText` derives from `TextView`.